# `SetWindowLong()` function doesn't change window style even after calling `SetWindowPos()`

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui, window-style

[image: normal static control] [image: sunken static control]

I create the static control with the code below:

```
hWnd = CreateWindowExW( 0,
                        L"STATIC",
                        Content.c_str(),
                        SS_LEFT | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD /*| SS_SUNKEN*/,
                        200,
                        120,
                        120,
                        40,
                        hWndParent,
                        NULL,
                        hInstance,
                        NULL);
```

If I enable the `SS_SUNKEN` style in the creation code above, the created static control appears sunken successfully.

But, what I'm trying to do is the change the control style after its creation.
I tried this:

```
void BaseWindowClass::AddStyle(DWORD NewStyle)
{
    // NewStyle     = 0x00001000 = SS_SUNKEN
    LONG oldstyle, changedstyle;
    oldstyle=SetWindowLongW(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, changedstyle=GetWindowLongW(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) | NewStyle);
    UpdateWindowStyles();
    // oldstyle     = 0x50000000
    // changedstyle = 0x50001000 (everything looks normal)
}
void BaseWindowClass::UpdateWindowStyles()
{
    BOOL success;
    success=SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
    // success = 0x00000001 (non-zero: SetWindowPos sucseeded)
}
```

Documentation:
[SetWindowLong()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[SetWindowPos()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I call `SetWindowPos()` after calling `SetWindowLongW()` because in the documentation of SetWindowLong, it says:

> Certain window data is cached, so changes you make using SetWindowLong will not take effect until you call the SetWindowPos function. Specifically, if you change any of the frame styles, you must call SetWindowPos with the SWP_FRAMECHANGED flag for the cache to be updated properly.

And, in the documentation of SetWindowPos, it says:

> If you have changed certain window data using SetWindowLong, you must call SetWindowPos for the changes to take effect. Use the following combination for uFlags: SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED.

Even after changing `SetWindowLongW()` and `SetWindowPos()` the style of my static control does not change.

What am I doing wrong, or what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`SS_SUNKEN` effectively sets `WS_EX_STATICEDGE` in the extended styles (`GWL_EXSTYLE`) window long, so you can update `GWL_EXSTYLE` appropriately and reposition as you're currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

Even though `SS_SUNKEN` does affect the frame of a static control, it isn't one of the "frame styles" that note is referring to.

That note refers to generic frame styles that affect all windows like `WS_BORDER` or `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE` - styles that require a recalculation of a window's non-client area when changed.

Many of the system controls cache their styles upon creation and don't update the cache even if you change the styles via `SetWindowLong`. I would guess that's what's happening here - if you don't create the static control with `SS_SUNKEN`, you can't add it later. Your best option would be to simply destroy and recreate the control with the new style.

Comment: +1. `SS_SUNKEN` is consulted only at creation. Changing it dynamically has no effect. If you want to change the effect dynamically, then don't use `SS_SUNKEN`. Instead, use `WS_EX_STATICEDGE`.